# Run two different sonar configurations in parallel with jenkins?

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, build.gradle

I am working on a project with multiple modules, let's say: big module, smallModuleA, small modules, and small modules. And I have a build. Gradle file which has a sonar configuration that I change when I want to scan all small modules or the big module. I have a Jenkins pipeline that has a sonar scan stage. My goal is to run two sonar scans with different configurations in parallel on Jenkins. Now I know how to make two steps or stages run in parallel on Jenkins. My main concern is how would I have two sonar configurations on the build. The Gradle file that that be referenced in each of those sonar stages that are being run on the Jenkins file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to parameterize the build:

```
if (hasProperty("do.scan.one")){
    sonarqube {
        properties {
            // do set up one
        }
    }
} else {
    sonarqube {
        properties {
            // do other set up
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would need to pass an additional command like argument in the non-default configuration:

```
./gradlew sonarqube -Pdo.scan.one
```

If it is easier to use environment variables, that is also possible. Just change the property check to a `System.getenv()` check.